# Setting modified flag in a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Say I have a class Car that has 2 properties:

`NSMutableArray *parts`
and
`BOOL modified`

`parts` is an array of custom object called `Part`. I want `modified` to be set to `YES` if any property of any `Part` in the array is modified.

Is this a good candidate for KVO or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What else do you want to do with this class?

Comment: @Adel This class is a model, so its main purpose is for data transport.

Comment: Could you not just have a week relationship between Part and its Car? Then in the `setModified:` method of Part, you could set the modified of Car too? I think using KVO would be a nice approach too though, perhaps better than my suggestion because it removed the need for a `Part` to know about a `Car`.

Comment: @JamesBedford Yes, definitely better if Part does not have to know about Car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES ! That's exactly what KVO is made for, and your use case is a typical usage for this :)